# Javascript to find list of javascripts running on browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

Could you please tell me whether there is anyway to find the list of java scripts running on browsers(firefox) using separate javascript?

Comment: What do you mean by list of javascripts? What do you expect this to return? Anyway, the browser security model doesn't allow scripts from one domain to know anything about scripts running in pages from a different domain.

Comment: If you tell us what you're actually trying to achieve by this then we can probably tell you a much better way.

Comment: But if javascript is used to detect running javascript, the running javascript will detect the running javascript which will detect the javascript detecting the running javascript ****head explodes****

Comment: Just search through DOM and get files ending by .js extention. Also scan Dom for <script> </script> its simple

Comment: Hi All. I have actually installed an extension in firefox which runs a javascript file browsercontent.js.. so i need to have an another JS file to detect whethere browsercontent.js is running..

Comment: i made several tries to build some kind of javascript taskmanager, but its horrible complicated because even if theres "no js" running from page theres much js beeing executed

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know if that 1 script has been included in the page then this will do that for you...

```
var browserContentLoaded = $("script[src$='browsercontent.js']").length;

if (browserContentLoaded) {
    // it's loaded - do relevant stuff
}
else {
    // it's not loaded - do relevant stuff
}
```

Ideally, though, you should check the script source to see if there are any window scope variables created, so that you can check for their existence instead (or even modify it to create one, if feasible).  The above code will only work if the script is included with the use of a `script` tag.

Comment: Hi.. this didn't work :( is there anyway to find the alert message sent by that browsercontent.js using another javascript?

Comment: How is the script included, when it is included?  Also, do you have a link so I could look at it?